# Вывод на экран после проверки условия типа boolean

Tags: java

```
public boolean isALessThenB (int a, int b) 
{ 
    a = 10; 
    b = 20;
    return a < b; 
}
```

Подскажите как вывести на экран результат этого метода `true` или `false`, выводит ошибку если пытаюсь прописать `System.out.println(isALessThenB(int a, int b));`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот полный код, выводящий результат сравнения в консоль:

```
public class Main {

    static public  void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(isALessThenB(10, 20));
    }

    public static boolean isALessThenB(int a, int b) { 
        return a < b; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Не шарю в java, но отвечу. Зачем Вам a и b в качестве параметров, если вы их задаете в самой функции?

Функция должна выглядеть вот так:

```
public boolean isALessThenB (int a, int b) 
{ 
return a < b; 
}
```

А чтобы вывести результат, пишите `System.out.println(isALessThenB(10, 20));`

Answer (score 1):

Напиши так

```
System.out.println(isALessThenB(123, 456))
```

Comment: Написал, но почему-то ничего не вывелось на экран. Process finished with exit code 0